# Python - Run multiple get requests in parallel and stop on first response

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

Python 3.4

requests 2.18

I want to make multiple `requests.get` calls and return the first that gets a response, stopping the rest. What's the best way to do this?

Edit: I ended up using python's `multiprocessing` module and a queue to achieve the result, like petre suggested in comments. Here's the code:

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
from multiprocessing.queues import Empty
from requests import head


def _req(url, queue):
    a = head(url)
    if a.status_code == 200:
        queue.put(a)
    return


def head_all_get_first(urls):
    jobs = []
    q = Queue()
    for url in urls:
        p = Process(target=_req, args=(url, q))
        jobs.append(p)
    for p in jobs:
        p.start()
    try:
        ret = q.get(timeout=20)  # blocking get - wait at most 20 seconds for a return
    except Empty:  # thrown if the timeout is exceeded
        ret = None
    for p in jobs:
        p.terminate()
    return ret
```

Comment: Have you already tried using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)? Just make a pool and use a queue to get results? Later you can stop the other processes when you get the first result.

Comment: @petre, I feel pretty dumb now. That worked for me. I don't have much experience with python's multiprocessing module so I didn't think to use it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Let's view the possibilities:

Python uses GIL-based execution stepping for principally [pure-**`[SERIAL]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5) code-execution, thus a maximum one can reach is a ["just"-**`[CONCURRENT]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5) flow of code-execution, not a [true-**`[PARALLEL]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5) system scheduling ( further details go way beyond this post, but are not needed now for presenting the below mentioned options ).

**Your description could be thus filled with either of:**
- using a distributed system ( a coordinated, multi-agent, bidirectionally talking network of processors )
- using a GIL-multiplexed python thread-based backend ( as in **`multiprocessing`** )
- using a GIL-independent python subprocess-based backend ( as in **`joblib`** )

In all cases, there will be different the sum of "costs" of a setup and termination of such a code-execution-infrastructure ( where a subprocess-based one will be the most expensive, as it always first generates a **full copy of the initial-state of the python interpreter**, including all its memory allocations et al, which is very expensive for "small pieces of meat to process", so if in a need for speed and shaving-off any latency down to any fraction of milliseconds, one may straight exclude this one ).

A nice example of a ( best a semi-persistent ) multi-agent network is using **ZeroMQ** or **nanomsg** inter-agent mediation tools ( where a wide range of transport classes `{ inproc:// | ipc:// | tcp:// | ... | vmci:// }`  allows one to operate smart solutions both in local/distributed layouts and your reaching a "first answered" state could be smart, fast and cheaply "advertised" to all the rest of the group of co-operating agents, that were not the first one.

[image]

Both the <kbd>**`Ventilator`**</kbd> and the <kbd>**`Sink`**</kbd> roles could be in the same python process, be them a class-method or in a form of some locally-multiplexed parts of an imperative code and also the uniform **`PUSH`**-strategy could grow smarter, if non-homogeneous tasking is coming to get implemented  (yet the principle of operating a smart network of multi-agent processing is the way to go ).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This approach is a bit too involved for what I'm trying to achieve. I'm sure it would be the more efficient route to use something like ZeroMQ, but I ended up going with a very simple multiprocessing approach using a queue, like @petre suggested. Thanks again for your detailed answer!